# How to combine multiple rows into one with for loop in R

Tags: r, regex

I want to extract numbered paragraphs from a legal document and store them as single observations in a dataframe, which will have one numerical variable called "para" that shows which number of paragraph, and one character variable called "text" with the paragraph text.

I have identified all paragraphs in the document with regex (see code below), but I am not able to loop through them in order to combine them into single observations.

Assume that the original document has more noise than the one I have presented below, and is around 100 pages long. All I want is to make a dataframe with all the extracted paragraphs.

Here is the example text:

> Blockquote

1. The following minor changes were made. Apple warned that the Python scripting
   language is deprecated and will eventually be removed. That nally happened in
   Monterey 12.3, released in March, 2022. Luckily, TeXShop does not use Python.
   Another deprecated item in macOS is the bash shell. The default shell changed from
   bash to zsh in 2019, but bash is still available in Monterey. It has not been upgraded
   in many years and could be removed in the future. To protect against that, shell
   scripts in TeXShop that previously used bash have been changed to use zsh. In most
   cases, the switch was trivial.
2. Herbert Schulz revised the latexmk and transparency engines in TeXShop in this
   way. The new versions are in in folders named
   GhostscriptTransparency Engines and Latexmk. The update to TeXShop did not
   change active engines because users may have edited these engines. Although most
   old latexmk and transparency engines continue to work, Schulz recommends updating
   them to the latest versions so he has a xed base for future changes.
3. When macOS is shut down, a dialog appears with an optional check box labeled
   Reopen windows when logging back in. If this is checked, all programs running
   when the machine was shut down will restart the next time the machine is rebooted.
   One user reported that TeXShop gets into an innite loop when restarted in this
   way, but after it is force quit and other programs are loaded, TeXShop runs without
   diculty. I could not reproduce this problem. TeXShop 4.70 has a hidden preference
   item for users who run into this problem. The item is called IgnoreStartOnReboot
   and has default value NO. To change it to YES, issue the following command in
   Terminal.
4. Defaults write TeXShop IgnoreStartOnReboot YES After this change, all other pro-
   grams will start when the machine is rebooted, but TeXShop will not. Restart
   TeXShop manually. The preference aects the behavior of the Restart item in the
   Apple menu in the same way. This preference does not modify the Open at Login
   list set for users in System Preferences, so if TeXShop is listed there, it will still start
   on login.
5. Latexmk is upgraded to version 4.77.
6. When an  Experiment source window closes, the related preview and console win-
   dows now also close. Thanks to Murray Eisenberg for reporting the bug.

> Blockquote

The desired result:

| para | text |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1. The following minor changes were made. Apple warned that the Python scripting language is deprecated and will eventually be removed. That nally happened in Monterey 12.3, released in March, 2022. Luckily, TeXShop does not use Python. Another deprecated item in macOS is the bash shell. The default shell changed from bash to zsh in 2019, but bash is still available in Monterey. It has not been upgraded in many years and could be removed in the future. To protect against that, shell scripts in TeXShop that previously used bash have been changed to use zsh. In most cases, the switch was trivial. |
| 2 | 2. Herbert Schulz revised the latexmk and transparency engines in TeXShop in this way. The new versions are in in folders named GhostscriptTransparency Engines and Latexmk. The update to TeXShop did not change active engines because users may have edited these engines. Although most old latexmk and transparency engines continue to work, Schulz recommends updating them to the latest versions so he has a xed base for future changes. |

So far I have tried the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(pdftools)
library(tm)



text <- c("1. The following minor changes were made. Apple warned that the Python scripting
language is deprecated and will eventually be removed. That nally happened in
Monterey 12.3, released in March, 2022. Luckily, TeXShop does not use Python.
Another deprecated item in macOS is the bash shell. The default shell changed from
bash to zsh in 2019, but bash is still available in Monterey. It has not been upgraded
in many years and could be removed in the future. To protect against that, shell
scripts in TeXShop that previously used bash have been changed to use zsh. In most
cases, the switch was trivial.

2. Herbert Schulz revised the latexmk and transparency engines in TeXShop in this
way. The new versions are in in folders named
GhostscriptTransparency Engines and Latexmk. The update to TeXShop did not
change active engines because users may have edited these engines. Although most
old latexmk and transparency engines continue to work, Schulz recommends updating
them to the latest versions so he has a xed base for future changes.

3. When macOS is shut down, a dialog appears with an optional check box labeled
Reopen windows when logging back in. If this is checked, all programs running
when the machine was shut down will restart the next time the machine is rebooted.
One user reported that TeXShop gets into an innite loop when restarted in this
way, but after it is force quit and other programs are loaded, TeXShop runs without
diculty. I could not reproduce this problem. TeXShop 4.70 has a hidden preference
item for users who run into this problem. The item is called IgnoreStartOnReboot
and has default value NO. To change it to YES, issue the following command in
Terminal.

4. Defaults write TeXShop IgnoreStartOnReboot YES After this change, all other pro-
grams will start when the machine is rebooted, but TeXShop will not. Restart
TeXShop manually. The preference aects the behavior of the Restart item in the
Apple menu in the same way. This preference does not modify the Open at Login
list set for users in System Preferences, so if TeXShop is listed there, it will still start
on login.

5. Latexmk is upgraded to version 4.77.

6. When an  Experiment source window closes, the related preview and console win-
dows now also close. Thanks to Murray Eisenberg for reporting the bug.")


text1 <- unlist(text)
text1 <- str_split(text1, pattern = "\n")
text2 <- unlist(text1)


number_starts <- which(str_detect(text2, "^([\\d]{1,3}\\.)"))
number_ends <- number_starts[(2:length(number_starts))-1]




#make empty dataframe
edf <- c()

for (x in 1:length(number_starts)) {
  
  n_s <- text2[number_starts[x]]
  n_e <- text2[number_ends[x]]
  
  df <- text2[n_s:n_e]
  
  
}
```

I only get the following warning and error code:

```
Error in n_s:n_e : NA/NaN argument
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In n_s:n_e : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In n_s:n_e : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I really appreciate any help on this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I'm getting right, what you want is a character vector with each element as paragraph.

Try changing the pattern argument from the `str_split()` function like this.

```
text <- c("1. The following minor changes were made. Apple warned that the Python scripting
language is deprecated and will eventually be removed. That nally happened in
Monterey 12.3, released in March, 2022. Luckily, TeXShop does not use Python.
Another deprecated item in macOS is the bash shell. The default shell changed from
bash to zsh in 2019, but bash is still available in Monterey. It has not been upgraded
in many years and could be removed in the future. To protect against that, shell
scripts in TeXShop that previously used bash have been changed to use zsh. In most
cases, the switch was trivial.

2. Herbert Schulz revised the latexmk and transparency engines in TeXShop in this
way. The new versions are in in folders named
GhostscriptTransparency Engines and Latexmk. The update to TeXShop did not
change active engines because users may have edited these engines. Although most
old latexmk and transparency engines continue to work, Schulz recommends updating
them to the latest versions so he has a xed base for future changes.

3. When macOS is shut down, a dialog appears with an optional check box labeled
Reopen windows when logging back in. If this is checked, all programs running
when the machine was shut down will restart the next time the machine is rebooted.
One user reported that TeXShop gets into an innite loop when restarted in this
way, but after it is force quit and other programs are loaded, TeXShop runs without
diculty. I could not reproduce this problem. TeXShop 4.70 has a hidden preference
item for users who run into this problem. The item is called IgnoreStartOnReboot
and has default value NO. To change it to YES, issue the following command in
Terminal.

4. Defaults write TeXShop IgnoreStartOnReboot YES After this change, all other pro-
grams will start when the machine is rebooted, but TeXShop will not. Restart
TeXShop manually. The preference aects the behavior of the Restart item in the
Apple menu in the same way. This preference does not modify the Open at Login
list set for users in System Preferences, so if TeXShop is listed there, it will still start
on login.

5. Latexmk is upgraded to version 4.77.

6. When an  Experiment source window closes, the related preview and console win-
dows now also close. Thanks to Murray Eisenberg for reporting the bug.")

text1 <- str_split(text, pattern = "\n\n") %>% unlist()
```

It will do the work...

If you want a data.frame

```
df <- tibble(paragraph = str_split(text, pattern = "\n\n") %>% unlist)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It will work on that specific text, but assume that the text has much more noise, and that I would have to first split into lines, and then with regex detect which line the numbered paragraphs are located. Say then that the first paragraph "1. Something", starts on line 33 and stops at line 40. I want to combine all content from line 33 to 40 into one line. Sorry for not being clearer.

Comment: isn't that something you will handle with you regex to pull out the relevant parts (lets not then call them paras)? so you need to get the parts first, join them and add them to a data frame (Say by create a single record df and binding rows together. [ALL in a while/for loop).